# Keeping amsmath font of 'Q' symbol in a equation when using mathptmx packet

Tags: fonts, amsmath

I use mathptmx packet but want to still keep amsmath font of 'Q' symbol in a equation.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
   $Q=1$
\end{document}
```

Results: [image]

**But**: I want to
[image]

Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, can you confirm which `TeX` engine you are following, i.e., `PDFLaTeX`, `XeLaTeX` or any?

Comment: I use Overleaf for editing.

Comment: In just one equation or *all* equations?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\newcommand \Q {\textit{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont Q}}}

\begin{document}
$\Q$
\end{document}
```

I have found out the solution to this problem, thanks for MadyYuvi's attention.